# Android/Google Maps: How to get different info windows for different markers?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, onclicklistener, infowindow

This is my first time working with `Google Maps` so sorry if this is a beginner problem. I am working on an app that connects to a portable sensor.  The sensor sends pollution data every 2 minutes. Every time I get new data, a marker is placed on google maps and I want to show the data in the info window of the markers so that you can see how the pollution differs depending on where you are.

My problem is that as of now, all my markers info windows are updated with the newest data. I need to make it so that every marker has their own separate info window with unique data.

I think that I need to implement `OnInfoWindowClickListener` somehow and also that I need the ID of every marker. I have tried to look at answers in other threads and so far I have not understood how I should solve this problem.

Appreciate any help I can get

**This is my code right now.**

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

  ....


/* Here we create the infoWindow **/
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_infowindow, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.infoText);
            tv.setText("CO2 data: "+String.valueOf(co_mV) + "mV" +"\n" + "N2 data: "+String.valueOf(no2_mV) +" mV");

            return v;
        }

        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {


            return null;

        }
    });

}

 ....

 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    if (!initiateApp) {
        if(location.distanceTo(mLastLocation) < 20) {
            markerArrayList.get(markerArrayList.size()-1).remove();
            markerArrayList.remove(markerArrayList.size()-1);
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Reading to close to last reading, replace last reading", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    if (markerArrayList.size() == 3) {
        markerArrayList.get(0).remove();
        markerArrayList.remove(0);
    }

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    markerArrayList.add(mCurrLocationMarker);

    mLastLocation = location;



    Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + Double.toString(location.getLatitude()));
    Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + Double.toString(location.getLongitude()));


    //move map camera

    if(initiateApp){
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
    }
    initiateApp = false;

    boolean contains = mMap.getProjection()
            .getVisibleRegion()
            .latLngBounds
            .contains(latLng);

    if(!contains){
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }
}
```

**EDIT** The data I want to show is "co_mV" and "no2_mV".

```
        @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);


        try {
            JSONObject parser = new JSONObject(values[0]);
            JSONObject d = parser.getJSONObject("d");
            co_mV = d.getInt("co_mV");
            no2_mV = d.getInt("no2_mV");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        newData();

        //response received from server
        Log.d("CO2", values[0]);
        long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
        time=new java.util.Date((long)timeStamp*1000);




        //process server response here....

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a infowWindowAdapter like this

```
public class YourCustomInfoWindowAdpater implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {
private final View mymarkerview;
private Context context;
private List<YourModelClass> nearByModel;
private Location currentMarker;

public YourCustomInfoWindowAdpater(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    currentMarker = new Location();
    mymarkerview = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
            .inflate(R.layout.custominfowindow, null);
}

public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    render(marker, mymarkerview);
    return mymarkerview;
}

public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    View v = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.custominfowindow, null);

    // Getting the position from the marker
    LatLng latLng = marker.getPosition();
    // Getting reference to the TextView to set latitude
  /*  TextView tvLat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lat);

    // Getting reference to the TextView to set longitude
    TextView tvLng = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_lng);

    // Setting the latitude
    tvLat.setText("Latitude:" + latLng.latitude);

    // Setting the longitude
    tvLng.setText("Longitude:"+ latLng.longitude);*/

    // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents
    return v;
}

private void render(Marker marker, View view) {
    TextView place_distance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.place_distance);

    // Add the code to set the required values
    // for each element in your custominfowindow layout file
}

public void setModels(List<YourModelclass> nearByModel) {
    this.nearByModel = nearByModel;
}
}
```

first of all call `YourCustomInfoWindowAdpater yourInfo=new YourCustomInfoWindowAdpater(this);`

then set `googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(yourInfo);`

and as soon as you get data call setModels method of yourcustominfowindowadpater in which pass your data model

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't understand what setModels do? Is that where I should put the co and no2 data?

Comment: Also what is place_distance?

Comment: place_distance is a textview in info window to show the relevant text.its in layout of info window . And set models will be used to update your data as soon as you have new data , the number of data in that model is equal to no of infowindow with data

Comment: I have edited the method that returns data in the map activity, the data I will display are 2 integers, co_mV and no2_mV. I will at most have 6 markers which are stored in a ArrayList. and if size of array == 6 I will remove the oldest marker. How would I then define the List<ModelClass>?

Comment: Then pass that arrayList in that method and declare relevant variable also as arrayList as assign values accordingly