# Google maps: can you make string inside snippet bold?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, infowindow

I have for a while been trying to make a custom info window that shows sensor data. My problem before was that I never solved how to make different info windows for different markers. All markers info windows were updated with the new data.

So in order to get around this problem I was thinking about using the original info window.

My code looks like

```
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("co: " +String.valueOf(co_mV) + " mV");
    markerOptions.snippet("no2: " + String.valueOf(co_mV) + " mV");
```

Is it possible to make the snippet bold or title not bold without creating your own info window? Because this would solve my problem.

Thanks.

**EDIT** Tried using custom info windwow. This made it so that all markers info windows were updated when I got new data.

```
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_infowindow, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.infoText);
            tv.setText("CO2 data: "+String.valueOf(co_mV) + "mV" +"\n" + "N2 data: "+String.valueOf(no2_mV) +" mV");

            return v;
        }

        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {


            return null;

        }
    });


}
```

Comment: `MarkerOptions` takes a `String`, not a `CharSequence`, and so I suspect that formatting is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom info window and style the contents.

**custom_info.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="#fff"
android:padding="10dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:id="@+id/snippet"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and then creating the custom info window as below

```
googlemap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
        View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info, null);
        TextView title= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView snippet= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.snippet);
        title.setText("your value");
        snippet.setText("your value");
        return v;
        }
@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
        return  null;

        }
        });

markerOptions.showInfoWindow();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I am not mistaken, this would not give each marker a different info window? But that all markers would share the same info window? So when I get new data, all markers would show the same data.

Comment: See edit for how I did it, this indeed makes it so that all markers info windows are updated when new data enters. Did I put it in the wrong method or?

Comment: I don't understand your both the terms _different info window_ and _share the same info window_

Comment: I am sorry. So basically every time I put a new marker on the map will be when I get new data. The newest data will be displayed in the info window of the newest marker. But I still want the older markers to show the old data in their info windows. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: as i understood that when you add a new marker. only the new marker popups..and the old markers disappear from map.? so you still want the old markers also to be showing up without disappearing

Comment: but when you add the new marker, does the old markers remain in the map without popup,, just the markers only remain?

Comment: When I add the new marker the old markers remain. When you press the old markers their info window with their data will show.

Comment: That only makes it so the infoWindow shows all the time right?

Comment: I think I may have phrased it wrongly. What I want: When I add the new marker the old markers remain. When you press the old markers their info window with their data will show. What I have: When I add the new marker, the old markers remain. When you press the old marker the new data will show, not the old data.

Comment: show me your code where you show the new marker popup and the old markers

Comment: Here is my old post with my code, I think this just might be out of my leauge when it comes to programming. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43370131/android-google-maps-how-to-get-different-info-windows-for-different-markers/43371150?noredirect=1#comment73814632_43371150